# Audio clicks with program generated wave

Tags: vb.net, audio

***NEWEST UPDATE: The wave files were NOT constructed properly! Thank you Jacket!***

UPDATE:  The wave files are now constructed properly and there is still a clicking that occurs when playSync() is used.  Loading the waves into a wave editor, they look and sound just fine.

I have a problem with the audio in my program.  There is a click at the end of the playback.  I am using vb.net with VS 2013.

The goal of this program is to playback morse code so the user can learn it.  Good sounding audio is  must.  On a radio that transmits morse code, there is a 5 millisecond ramp on the start and the end of the tone/beep to eliminate harsh popping and clicking in the  receiving radios.  I want the audio of this program to emulate that,  so I have added a 'ramp' in the generation of the sine wave.  Most listeners will hear the morse tone between  400 and 1000 Hz.

I believe there  should be enough comments in the code to understand what is going on.  I am not a programmer.

The wave is generated as a memory stream and passed to system.media.player via player = system.media.player, a stream is then set with player.stream = ditstream (ditstream is a wave format audio)  then played with player.playsync().

I have added zeros to the end of the generated wave and it helped a little.

**Here is the code to generate the wave:**

```
Function createWave(ByRef genStream As MemoryStream, ByVal frequency As UInt16, ByVal msDuration As Integer, _
                    Optional msRamp As Integer = 5, Optional ByVal volume As UInt16 = 16383) ' 16383
    'set variables
    Dim writer As New BinaryWriter(genStream)
    Dim TAU As Double = 2 * Math.PI
    Dim formatChunkSize As Integer = 16
    Dim headerSize As Integer = 8
    Dim formatType As Short = 1
    Dim tracks As Short = 1
    Dim samplesPerSecond As Integer = 44100
    Dim bitsPerSample As Short = 16
    Dim frameSize As Short = CShort(tracks * ((bitsPerSample + 7) \ 8))
    Dim bytesPerSecond As Integer = samplesPerSecond * frameSize
    Dim waveSize As Integer = 4
    Dim samples As Integer = CInt(Math.Truncate(CType(samplesPerSecond, [Decimal]) * msDuration \ 1000))   'removed /1000 from both
    Dim rampSamples As Integer = CInt(Math.Truncate(CType(samplesPerSecond, [Decimal]) * msRamp \ 1000))   'number of samples for ramp
    Dim fullSamples As Integer = samples - (rampSamples * 2)         'number of samples at full amplitude
    Dim dataChunkSize As Integer = samples * frameSize
    Dim fileSize As Integer = waveSize + headerSize + formatChunkSize + headerSize + dataChunkSize
    ' var encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    writer.Write(&H46464952) ' = encoding.GetBytes("RIFF")
    writer.Write(fileSize)
    writer.Write(&H45564157) ' = encoding.GetBytes("WAVE")
    writer.Write(&H20746D66) ' = encoding.GetBytes("fmt ")
    writer.Write(formatChunkSize)
    writer.Write(formatType)
    writer.Write(tracks)
    writer.Write(samplesPerSecond)
    writer.Write(bytesPerSecond)
    writer.Write(frameSize)
    writer.Write(bitsPerSample)
    writer.Write(&H61746164) ' = encoding.GetBytes("data")
    writer.Write(dataChunkSize)
    Dim theta As Double = frequency * TAU / CDbl(samplesPerSecond - 1)
    ' 'volume' is UInt16 with range 0 thru Uint16.MaxValue ( = 65 535)
    ' we need 'amp' to have the range of 0 thru Int16.MaxValue ( = 32 767)
    Dim amp As Double = volume >> 2 ' so we simply set amp = volume / 2
    Dim rampAmp As Double = 0

    'create amplification ramp of wave  for number of ramp samples (duration of msRamp)
    For [step] As Integer = 0 To rampSamples - 1
        rampAmp = [step] / rampSamples
        Dim s As Short = CShort(Math.Truncate((amp) * Math.Sin(theta * CDbl([step]))))
        s = s * rampAmp
        writer.Write(s)
        'Debug.Print("Step :" & [step] & " Ramp at beginning: " & rampAmp & " S Value :" & s)
    Next [step]

    amp = volume >> 2 
    ' create regular amplitude wave for full duration minus ending ramp
    For [step] As Integer = rampSamples To fullSamples - 1 
        Dim s As Short = CShort(Math.Truncate(amp * Math.Sin(theta * CDbl([step]))))
        writer.Write(s)
        'Debug.Print("Step: " & [step] & "  Full Amp sample : " & s)
    Next [step]
```

***UPDATE:  THIS SECTION BELOW IS NO LONGER A PROBLEM!***
**==================================================================================
          THIS ROUTINE BELOW IS MALFORMING THE SINE WAVE CAUSING CLICKS!**

```
        'create ending ramp amplfication from full volume to 0
        For [step] As Integer = (rampSamples + fullSamples) To (((2 * rampSamples) + fullSamples - 1))   'removed -1 for testing (((2 * rampSamples) + fullSamples -1))
            rampAmp = CDbl((rampSamples + fullSamples + rampSamples - [step]) / rampSamples)
            Dim s As Short = CShort(Math.Truncate((amp) * Math.Sin(theta * CDbl([step]))))
            s = s * rampAmp
            'debug statement
            'Debug.Print("Step: " & [step] & "   RampAmp at ending : " & rampAmp & "  S value : " & s)
            Debug.Print("Step : " & [step] & "  Value : " & s & vbCrLf)
            writer.Write(s)
            If [step] = (((2 * rampSamples) + fullSamples) - 1) Then Debug.Print("End [STEP] = " & [step] & vbCrLf)
        Next [step]
```

**==================================================================================**

This is ok....I think....

```
 'add extra zero at end for good measure
            'Dim z As Short = 0
            'writer.Write(z)
            'add some extra 0's to clean up any noise!   Cheap and dirty fix!
            For [x] = 0 To 200
                writer.Write(0)
            Next
            Debug.Print("generateWave stream length: " & genStream.Length)


            Return genStream
```

**Here is a sample of the code for playback :**

```
         Sub playDit()

            ditStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
            player.Stream = ditStream
            player.PlaySync()

        End Sub
```

Here is the link for the Git:
[Morse Git Code](https://github.com/Schmitty2005/MorseDecode.git)

**I am not a programmer!  Just trying to learn!**
Any help removing audio clicks and pops will be appreciated!

Suggestions will be helpful.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with vb.net, but I suspect that the right hand of the rampAmp assignment is doing an integer division. Try coercing either the numerator or denominator to a double before the division. e.g. `rampAmp = [step] / CDbl(rampSamples)`

Comment: Still clicks in audio wave.  I believe the problem has to do with length of the wave file in the header versus the actual length of the wave.  Something is thrown off somewhere in that regards. I checked and nothing stands out......

Comment: Can you you attach a link to a saved wav file?

Comment: I have not uploaded the files yet, but when I looked them over with Audacity, I could see ONE HALF of a sine wave was malformed at the beginning of the 'ending ramp'.  Thank you for your willingness to help. I will let you know when I upload the wave files. Any suggestions for a better ending (volume adjusting)  ramp methodology?

Comment: Again, I think you're problem is due to an integer divide. Try changing to `rampAmp = CDbl(rampSamples + fullSamples + rampSamples - [step]) / rampSamples`. Notice how I'm just converting the numerator to a double rather than the result of the divide.

Comment: rampAmp is working as it should.  I goes from 0.00 to 1.00 on the beginning  and from 1.000 to 0.00 on the ending ramp.  I assume that if there was integer division it rampamp would simply be 1 or 0. Is that assumption correct?  When i watch the variable, it changes to 0.012023234 or whatever, and continues to rise or decline as it should, giving  a 'percentage' or a fraction in which the amplitude can be adjusted by.  I Will also try to post a picture of the wave....

Comment: My method of creating the 'ramp' is causing some sort of problem.  It will not allow the sine wave to be smooth at the transition! Is there a logarithmic type formula that can be used instead of a linear formula like I am using?

Comment: And I will continue working on adjusting the rampAmp to a CDbl incase it is causing some miscalculations. Thank you again!

Comment: Here is a link to the wave files.  They are now correct but there is still a clicking when PlaySync() is used.

https://sites.google.com/site/githubwaves/home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at the dahwave.wav, analyzing it back to back. The first thing is that where two copies of the waveform are joined together, there is a glitch. There is also a glitch at a the 5th cycle in. Presumable, this is where you are changing from the ramp to the full scale waveform.

Secondly, anytime you have a sharp corner in your waveform, you have to possibility of introducing a click or pop. Since your ramp is a straight line, you have a corner at the beginning and end of the ramp. Typically, one would use a smoother function for the window. A practical one in this case is a cosine-squared or hann window.

To implement this you can just have a single loop:

```
For [step] As Integer = 0 To samples-1
    a = 0.5 * (1 - Math.Cos(2*Math.PI*i/CDbl(samples));
    Dim s As Short = CShort(Math.Truncate(amp * a * Math.Sin(theta * CDbl([step]))))
    writer.Write(s)
Next [step]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you!  I was using Audacity to view the wave files, they did not stand out, and I did not know that such a seemingly small error would cause a click.  I will update my code using your suggested solution.  Thank you much!

What program are you using to analyze the waves?  Or was that the audio output being analyzed?

Comment: a = 0.5 * (1 - Math.Cos(2*Math.PI*i/CDbl(samples)); Should 'i' be [step] in this example?

Comment: Yeah, I should be step. The software is from the company I work for but it comes along with a very expensive (hardware) dongle ;)